# Append line length at end of each line

Tags: unix, shell-script

Given input:

```
tree
branch
```

the desired output is

```
tree 4
branch 6
```

What is a *nix available command that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple **shell script** which does this:

```
#!/bin/sh
while read line; do
    printf -- '%s %d\n' "${line}" "${#line}";
done < "${1}"
```

save the script as e.g. `lc`, make it executable and run it on file names as

```
lc myfile
```

---

Or with **`awk`**:

```
awk '{print $0, length()}' myfile
```

---

Or with **Perl**:

```
perl -nle 'print $_." ".length($_)' myfile
```